# Best Practices for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Auto Scaling Trigger Settings for Web Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

By default when you create an elastic beanstalk application, the scaling is set to scale based on "Average network out", and add instance when > 6000000, and remove instance when < 2000000.

What's the best practice for setting trigger settings for these? These default settings are obviously terrible, as we just had a bunch of ELB errors because our servers couldn't handle the traffic, the CPU wasn't high either, this was on t2.micro servers.

Previously, I've always used the CPU trigger, but I understand a server can stop accepting request, even before the CPU is maxed out.

What are some of the general best practices you use when setting the auto scaling trigger?

I can't seem to find any really, it just leaves you to try and come up with them by yourself.  This is just for a standard web application, and server size may change over time. So what's one setting I can just generally use for everything?

Comment: Without making an answer out of it, I don't consider t2.micro instances appropriate for even moderate consistent loads.  Beyond that, you need to have a better idea of _why_ the requests failed.  There are so many possible reasons: out of database connections, or connections to the server application or middleware, whatever's running; a software error causing unforeseen latency, maybe at higher volumes... guessing isn't likely to come up with a solution.  But experiment with bigger instances, if only to rule it out.  Use multiple ASGs if it suits you, per instance type.